# wrapper.conf in mule i am unable to find wrapper.conf file,

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component

wrapper.conf in mule
i am unable to find wrapper.conf file,

please help me where does it resides, I know it will be in MULE_HOME, but where exactly, I am unable to find MULE_HOME as well.

Please help me with the root directory structure.

Thanx

Comment: When I run a mule app in Anypoint Studio, the console logs show "MULE_HOME is set to ... "

Answer (score 1):

`MULE_HOME` should refer to the root of your installed mule runtime.

You will find your `wrapper.conf` at `MULE_HOME/conf/wrapper.conf`